# Is it bad to have too little or too much resistance?

Tags: resistors

OK I need a 27kOhm resistor and I don't like shopping online. 
So, I was just wondering if it is bad to have a resistor with a too high or too low value.  I was at Radioshack and all they had was 22kOhm and 33kOhm, but not 27kOhm.

I am building an FM transmitter that calls for a 27kOhm, but I really don't want to order online.

So, can you please tell me if a different value would be OK or if I can use the available value resistors in some way.

The transmitter I am building is this one:

http://i1.wp.com/cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2013/10/kogawa_simplest_transmitter.png?zoom=3&resize=620%2C354

Diagram:
[image]

Comment: For an FM transmitter, substituting a different value probably won't work.

Comment: OK thanks for the quick rreply.but just In case I wanna wait for other people too.

Comment: Without a schematic we're really not going to be able to tell you. Most likely some reduction in performance..

Comment: make a series of two parallels of 24k and 33k. If I computed it correctly, it's just about 27k. (2* 1/ (1/24 + 1/33)) = 27.8k (more or less 27k). And if you use a 22 for one and a 24 for the other... you fall flat on the 27k line.

Comment: Do not bother; judging by schematics it will work fine. However, schematic as a whole looks suspicious - too primitive.

Comment: Why not SPICE it and see? Although I am also highly sceptical of that schematic - to me, the "simplest" possible FM transmitter is a VCO, and I don't see any varactors in there.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to do this; serial and parallel.

Serial, you just add the two resistors.  Normally, one would go to a standard reference like [this listing](http://www.brannonelectronics.com/images/STANDARD%20VALUE.pdf) to find various 1% resistors available.  Note there is a value (26.7K) which is pretty close to what you need. However you said you are getting parts from RadioShack, so you are constrained to the values they have.

RadioShack has a 500 piece assortment of resistors with quite a few different values.  They [are listed here.](http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/500-piece-1-4-watt-carbon-film-resistor-assortment/2710312.html#.VWFVSUbQMZ8)

Since they have both 12K and 15K values, you can just put them in series and get 27K.

The other way is to put them in parallel.  The formula is:

$$R = \frac{R1 \times R2}{R1 + R2}$$

This is a pain to calculate manually using pairs of available resistors, but a [parallel resistance calculator](http://www.1728.org/resistrs.htm) makes it a little easier.  You need to plug in values from the RadioShack table until you get the desired resistance.  I found that 150K in parallel with 33K gives a value of 27.049K.